# Arquivo temporario com indy

Tags: delphi-7

Bom, estou tentando baixar um arquivo de texto e fazer com que um RichEdit pegue o conteúdo desse arquivo. Mas não sei muito bem como fazer. 
Tentei assim:

```
news := 'http://pokestage.ddns.net/patch/patchlist.txt';
sRichEdit1.Lines[1] := IdHTTP2.Get(news);
```

Eu sei que não funciona, porque tipo do Get do IdHttp não é string, gostaria de saber como fazer. 
PS: O arquivo contém várias linhas. Desde já, obrigado.

Edit: 
Consegui assim:

```
news := 'http://pokestage.ddns.net/patch/News.txt';
sRichEdit1.Text := IdHTTP2.Get(news);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fazendo uso da classe [`TIdHTTP`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdHTTP.html) do *Indy*, podes fazer da seguinte forma:

```
http.ExecuteURL('http://pokestage.ddns.net/patch/patchlist.txt');
sRichEdit1.Lines.Add(http.sl.Text);
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas consegui de outra forma.

Comment: Partilha o teu conhecimento e responde à tua pergunta com o teu método, poderá ajudar outros no futuro :)